# mikro-orm CLI: Cannot find module 'ts-node'

Tags: node.js, typescript, package.json, ts-node, mikro-orm

I'm attempting to use the mikro-orm CLI but am getting a ts-node error:

```
 $ npx mikro-orm debug
npx: installed 280 in 14.531s
(node:19228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node'Require stack:
- C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache\_npx\19228\node_modules\mikro-orm\dist\cli\CLIHelper.js 
- C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache\_npx\19228\node_modules\mikro-orm\dist\cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)  
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
```

My package.json has the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev2": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "start2": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.3"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "useTsNode": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  }
```

I'm using the **'watch'** and **'dev'** scripts to run currently, ts-node also works fine with the script **'start2'**

My folder structure is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BGMT.png

This is new to me and I can't figure out what the problem is. Do you know what it could be?

Thank You!

Comment: Upgrade all packages to latest version, you are on the very first alpha, latest is rc.6

Comment: Also try downgrading to ts-node 8 if it wont help

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I did try downgrading to ts-node 8 previously, which didn't work. However, upgrading all the mikro-orm packages solved this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by @MartinAdámek 'Upgrade all packages to latest version, you are on the very first alpha, latest is rc.6'

Comment: Please include the a quote from the comment to make this an actual Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer should be that your mikro-orm configuration inside package.json says useTsNode: true. Change it to false and it wont complain about missing ts-node.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue. Ts-node can be useful in the case where someone wants to use ts files directly with the mikro-orm CLI.